# Потоковая длительность хранения

Tags: c++, c++11

В каких случаях переменной нужно давать "потоковую" длительность хранения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, в тех случаях, когда требуется, чтобы переменная была ассоциирована с потоком, а не со всем процессом.

[Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) приводит в качестве примера `errno`, которая будучи обычной глобальной переменной может быть "испорчена" другим потоком выполнения. Если же её объявить как `thread_local`, то в каждом потоке будет существовать свой экземпляр под именем `errno`.